# Fourier Series on Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, mathematica

Trying to find the first few terms of the Fourier series of $e^{x^2}$ on Mathematica, but my code doesn't seem to be working. It says the first few terms are all 0. Can anyone look at it and tell me whats wrong?

`ClearAll[f, a, aa, s]
f[x_] := Exp[x^2];
a[n_] := Integrate[(1/Pi) f[x] Sin[n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
aa = Table[a[k], {k, 1, 7}]
s[x_, n_] := Sum[aa[[k]] Sin[k x], {k, 1, n}];`

Comment: You have an even function, so the sine-terms must vanish The program worked correctly.

Comment: @Peter So the terms are 0?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the cosines. Then, everything will work fine.

Comment: @Peter Understood So, when we finally sum (the last line of code), it should be Cos[kx]?

Comment: Exactly , and of course also above.

Comment: You mean also in the 3rd line of code?

Comment: Yes, then the program should do the job.

Comment: Got a bunch of imaginary terms. Does that seem alright/fair?

Comment: The integrals (and therefore the coefficients) should be real. Maybe Mathematica calculated the expression symbolic. Try to force numerical calculation instead.

Comment: (I E^(25/4) (Erf[5/2 - I \[Pi]] - 
   Erf[5/2 + I \[Pi]]))/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), (I E^9 (Erf[3 - I \[Pi]] - 
   Erf[3 + I \[Pi]]))/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), (I E^(
 49/4) (Erf[7/2 - I \[Pi]] - Erf[7/2 + I \[Pi]]))/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) is what we get

Comment: What does the last line do ? Showing cos(kx) as a text or does it actually calculate the sum ?

Comment: @Peter Pretty sure it calculates it. Its in there, I mean

Comment: But it should only calculate the coefficients, and this numerically.

Comment: @Peter So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Instead of the sum create a vector with the coefficients.